# Wifi driver for ASUS VivoBook X510UQ

Tags: networking, drivers, laptop, asus, iwlwifi

I can not make the wifi driver working on my Asus VivoBook X510UQ laptop. I am in Ubuntu 16.04.

Result of `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 02801`:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 [8086:24fd] (rev 78)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265 [8086:0010]
```

Result of `sudo lshw -C network`:

```
   *-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Network controller
       product: Wireless 8265 / 8275
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 78
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:ef100000-ef101fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: enp0s20f0u1
       serial: ba:80:84:0a:4f:05
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.191 link=yes multicast=yes
```

Result of `rfkill list`:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

I installed the `Intel® Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265` firmware from [Linux* Support for Intel® Wireless Adapters](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html), but it does not work.

Comment: May we also see: `uname -r` and also: `modinfo iwlwifi | grep 24FD`

Comment: I've installed ubuntu 17.10, and it is working fine now. This laptop has some new hardware which is not supported by 16.04