# Missing Wifi Driver for Asus X510U Vivo Book

Tags: 14.04, drivers, wireless, 17.04

I have a similar issue like [this AskUbuntu post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/978850/wifi-driver-for-asus-vivobook-x510uq),
where **ubuntu 14.04.5** LTS **is missing some new wifi driver**,
and when I install **ubuntu 17.04, the wifi works fine**.
However, ubuntu 17.04 gives me a hard time
building packages from source that went super smooth
with ubuntu 14.04. How is it possible to install missing wifi driver
and make ubuntu 14.04 use it? any help is very much appreciated, thanks!

EDIT:

The output of

```
lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
```

Is:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 [8086:24fd] (rev 78)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265 [8086:0010]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

Thanks!

Comment: Let's start by identifying your wireless device. Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 thanks, I have added the lspci output